# Proof of prime numbers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification

Prove that for every integer $m \geq 2$, if there is no prime number $p$ such that $p \leq \sqrt{m}$ and $p \mid m$ (evenly divides), then $m$ must be prime.

Don't even know where to start with this one.

*Edit: In class we covered the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic, but again I'm not sure how to start applying it.

Comment: Suppose the contrary that $m$ is composite and let $q$ be its smallest prime factor. Consider $m/q$.

Comment: I upvoted to reverse the (anonymous, silent) downvote, because I regard it as premature.  The idea is that a mathSE reviewer is unhappy (as I also am) that you have not provided background or detailed your work.  What is the problem's **background**?  Is it from a contest, book, class, or what...?  If from a book or class, what theorems or previously solved problems do you regard as pertinent.  Please edit your query to include the background. ...see next comment.

Comment: Further, having gathered the problem's background, regard this as a set of tools.  Please try to solve the problem by using these tools.  Then, please edit your query to show your work.

Comment: @user2661923 Background? I find THAT an irritating position to hold.  The math problem doesnt change depending on the context under which it was asked.  The question is a math question, this is a math forum. I fail to see why people cant just answer questions if they know how to, and if they dont know how to they should bow out of the conversation entirely.  Who participates in a Q&A forum and refuses to answer questions, but mocks and criticizes the people who asks them instead?  I dont need the asker to justify why he asked the question.

Comment: I had learnt that proof at school , but there we used the fundamental theorem of arithmetic.

Comment: You do not need the FTA for this. It is a middle school stuff.

Comment: @CogitoErgoCogitoSum See the **Provide Context** answer to 
https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question.  So, this isn't my policy but a policy adopted by the site.  Personally, when the OP has shown no work, not only is this a turn-off because the site is not a homework answering machine, but also, responders are unsure what level of math to answer the question with.  An answer needs to **dovetail** with the background of the [OP + his book/class].

Comment: @CogitoErgoCogitoSum  Personally, I *often* have a separate purpose: often the OP will quite legitimately say "I don't know what to do here".  To my mind, the answer is simple - **meta-cheat** by gathering the *tools* re the background, and trying to use these tools to attack.

Comment: @CogitoErgoCogitoSum By the way, I agree with the idea of *also* giving a helpful hint as others have done here.  The only reason that I didn't, is because I'm unsure what hint would help.  My sophistication re *teaching* number theory is **very limited.**

Comment: If $p|m$, then $m$ is not prime because it has a prime factor (why is it non-trivial?).

Comment: Hint: in line with Chris Cutter's answer : suppose $p|m$, where $p$ is a prime $> \sqrt{m}.$  Then what can you say about $\frac{m}{p}$ which would have to be an integer?  How would this fraction compare with $\sqrt{m}?$ Another way of verbalizing the question: is it possible for $m = a \times b$, where $a$ and $b$ are **each** $> \sqrt{m}$?

Answer (score 1):

This is basically the *Sieve of Eratosthenes*.  The point is that once you pass $\sqrt m$, you have already exhausted the possibilities.  Take $11$.  Then you only need to check up to $\sqrt{11}$ for factors, because anything bigger than $\sqrt{11}$ would need to be paired with something less than $\sqrt{11}$.  None of $2,3$ is a factor, so we have proved that $11$ is prime.